# How does 'build artifacts' work in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

How does 'build artifacts' work in IntelliJ IDEA?
I guess I can execute it using the Java command.

What specific commands does it execute?

For example, how should I use 'build artifacts' for a Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Thank you for your answer.